# Installing Samba 4.0.7 on CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos, yum, samba, python, repository

CentOS 6.4's yum repo has only 4.0.0.  I see some major security and stability patches since then.

So I signed up for SerNet, and followed their directions to install their GPG key.  Then I did:

```
sudo yum -y install sernet-samba*
```

The output ends with:

```
> Transaction Summary
> ================================================================================================================================ Install      34 Package(s)
> 
> Total size: 36 M Installed size: 157 M Downloading Packages: Running
> rpm_check_debug Running Transaction Test
> 
> 
> Transaction Check Error:   file
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tdb.so from install of
> sernet-samba-ad-4.0.7-2.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package
> python-tdb-1.2.10-1.el6.i686   file
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/talloc.so from install of
> sernet-samba-ad-4.0.7-2.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package
> pytalloc-2.0.7-2.el6.i686   file
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ldb.so from install of
> sernet-samba-ad-4.0.7-2.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package
> pyldb-1.1.13-3.el6.i686   file
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/_tevent.so from install of
> sernet-samba-ad-4.0.7-2.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package
> python-tevent-0.9.17-1.el6.i686   file
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tevent.pyc from install of
> sernet-samba-ad-4.0.7-2.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package
> python-tevent-0.9.17-1.el6.i686   file
> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tevent.pyo from install of
> sernet-samba-ad-4.0.7-2.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package
> python-tevent-0.9.17-1.el6.i686
> 
> Error Summary
> -------------
```

...and then back to prompt.  Does this mean I need to upgrade python or something?  I have installed:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 21 2013, 23:54:59)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
```

Not new enough?

Also

```
$ rpm -qi python-tevent
Name        : python-tevent                Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 0.9.17                            Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 1.el6                         Build Date: Fri 22 Feb 2013 01:47:57 AM EST
Install Date: Thu 04 Jul 2013 09:56:11 AM EDT      Build Host: c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org
Group       : Development/Libraries         Source RPM: libtevent-0.9.17-1.el6.src.rpm
Size        : 16963                            License: LGPLv3+
Signature   : RSA/SHA1, Sat 23 Feb 2013 12:52:51 PM EST, Key ID 0946fca2c105b9de
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
URL         : http://tevent.samba.org/
Summary     : Python bindings for the Tevent library
Description :
Python bindings for libtevent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of previous samba install dependencies:

```
$ sudo yum -y erase libtevent
$ sudo yum -y erase python-tdb
$ sudo yum -y erase pytalloc
```

And then:

```
$ sudo yum -y install sernet-samba*
```

...will work.  Although `yum` depends on python, it does not seem to depend on `python-tdb` or `pytalloc`, at least for `erase` and `install`, because this worked.

Answer (score 2):

The package

```
python-tevent
```

that the sernet-samba packages conflict with, is most likely a result of a previous CentOS installation of samba. Check with

```
rpm -qi python-tevent | grep Repository
```

which repository it is from. If it is from "base", remove it first then try again.

Note also that simply checking the version number of samba is not enough; RedHat backports security fixes as appropriate (and of course, CentOS inherits these as well). See their page about it at https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting/?sc_cid=3093.

Comment: Wow, how did you know that?  I guess `yum erase` doesn't clean up after itself the way I thought it did.  I'll give this a shot later/tomorrow...thanks!

Comment: Actually, running `rpm -qi python-tevent | grep Repository` even as root shows nothing.  Without the grep, see question edit.

Comment: I found your link to RedHat's backporting page helpful.  However, in the case of Samba 4, it looks like I'd want a newer version anyway--it looks from http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/centos-rhel-x86_64/samba4-4.0.0-55.el6.rc4.x86_64.rpm.html like it hasn't been touched since January '13, but since then security and crashing bugs have been fixed.  It's possible the security vulnerabilities were only caused by bugfixes in the first place, but I'd still like to have crashing bugs fixed before I use it.